# Memory errors while finding node in binary tree

Tags: c, memory-management, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So this function is supposed to find a node with the *phone* value. 
The problem is with memory management. My function doesn't cope well when the input value isn't in the binary tree.

Where exactly is my problem? There is clearly something I don't understand here.

The function:

```
bst_node* find_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone) {

bst_node* x = bst->root;
    if(x == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(x->phone == phone)
        return bst->root;

    while (x->phone != phone && (x->left != NULL && x->right != NULL) ){
        if(phone <= x->phone){
             x = x->left;}
        else{x = x->right;}
    }
    if (x->phone == phone){
        return x;}
    else{return NULL;} 

}
```

Here's what Valgrind spits out. Both when a node is found and when it isn't.

```
Exiting...
==591== 
==591== HEAP SUMMARY:
==591==     in use at exit: 44 bytes in 7 blocks
==591==   total heap usage: 20 allocs, 13 frees, 7,260 bytes allocated
==591== 
==591== 44 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==591==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==591==    by 0x401427: bst_insert_node (introprog_telefonbuch.c:23)
==591==    by 0x400AAE: read_file (introprog_main_telefonbuch.c:54)
==591==    by 0x400D06: main (introprog_main_telefonbuch.c:119)
==591== 
==591== LEAK SUMMARY:
==591==    definitely lost: 44 bytes in 7 blocks
==591==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==591==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==591==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==591==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==591== 
==591== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==591== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**EDIT:**

Alright, I think the main problem might be in this function, which is supposed to free the subtree starting on a chosen node:

```
void bst_free_subtree(bst_node* node) {
    if(node == NULL){
        return;}
    else{
        bst_free_subtree(node->left);
        bst_free_subtree(node->right);
        free(node);
    }
}
```

And here is the function that inserts a new node in the tree:

```
void bst_insert_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone, char *name) {
    if(find_node(bst, phone) != NULL){
        return;}
    // Use calloc, memset, or manually set all values to NULL
    bst_node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(bst_node));

    new_node->phone = phone;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    char *dup = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);

    if (dup != NULL)
       strcpy(dup, name);

    new_node->name = dup; 

    bst_node* y = NULL;
    bst_node* x = bst->root;

    while(x != NULL)
    {
        y = x;
        if(phone <= x->phone)
             x = x->left;
        else x = x->right;
    }
    if (y == NULL)
    {
        bst->root = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        if (phone <= y->phone)
             y->left = new_node;
        else
            y->right = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s an error about a memory leak. It’s not directly caused by a search, since that doesn’t allocate memory.

Comment: Your are not creating memory error from this function. The error comes from the numbers of allocations and the number of frees. (20 allocs for 13 frees). I think you are running valgrind with an additional flags that make your appear the memory leaks. You need to correctly free your binary tree at the end of your program in order to fix your valgrind

Comment: Every `malloc` in the code needs to be matched by exactly one `free`. Since the code you've posted has no `malloc`s and no `free`s, there's not much more that can be said. See [mcve].

Comment: (But note that your search isn’t correct for BSTs in general, because `x->left != NULL && x->right != NULL` is too strict – the key can still be in `x->left` when `x->right == NULL` and vice versa. If you’re somehow relying on a correct search implementation to avoid memory leaks, that’s the thing to fix.)

Comment: @Ry- Thank you a lot the help! I edited my post with my functions that either allocate or free memory. Do you find anything wrong with those?

Comment: We probably will need enough code to replicate the error.

Comment: Oh, so it is indirect. Your insert implementation will use `find_node` and incorrectly determine that a node is missing, resulting in an existing one being overwritten and leaked. (Insert doesn’t really need to call find, though, it’s already doing all of the same work.)

Comment: @Ry- Alright I understand. So how could I check if I'm inserting a node with the same phone value without using find_node?

Comment: In `bst_free_subtree()` you don't `free` the strings you duplicated in the insert function.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks! How could I fix that?

Comment: Right before `free(node);` add `free(node->name);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're an angel thank you